# How can I treat a string as a Rust type?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I have a set of strings that I *know* represent Rust types. I want to be able to use syntax like:

```rust
fn assert_send<T: Send>() {}

let set_of_strings = get_types_as_strings();

for type_name in set_of_strings.iter() {
    assert_send<type_name>();
}
```

Is this achievable in Rust? Can I do this with a macro somehow?

Comment: AFAIK no. Beyond that, your example can't make sense because type / trait constraints are evaluated at compile time, so you can't call `assert_send` at runtime anyway.

Comment: If you know the full set of values the strings can take on, then you can do this manually or with a macro just by covering all the cases and matching on them. If you can't, then you're probably out of luck. Type information is long gone in the compiled executable.

Comment: This certainly feels like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/281829)

Comment: You're probably right, I was trying to know if there was some way to get type information at runtime, which you answered. Thanks!